# How to format javascript date Pacific Standard Time to Today Format

Tags: javascript, date

Here is my issue: I'm trying to get the last week date in Javascript but for some reason I'm getting the date not in the correct format.

Instead of getting the date in this format:
dd-mm-yyy

I'm getting :
Thu Mar 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

How can I convert it what I desire???

JS Function:

```
//================================= //
    // Search By Given Range           //
    // ============================== //
     function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
            var From = $find("<%= rdpFromDate.ClientID %>");
            var To = $find("<%= rdpToDate.ClientID %>");
            var nowDate = new Date();
                From.clear();
                To.clear();
                var lastWeekPeriod = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() - 7);

                From.set_selectedDate(lastWeekPeriod);
                To.set_selectedDate(nowDate);
        }
```

aspx Code:

```
 From:   <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpFromDate" runat="server" Width="135px"> </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

To:

```
 <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpToDate" runat="server" Width="135px"> </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Comment: Have you checked Date documentation on MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples

Comment: didn't helped me sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of,

```
var lastWeekPeriod = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate() - 7);
```

Do something like,

```
//var given_str = "Thu Mar 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";
//var nowDate = new Date(given_str);
console.log("yyyy=", nowDate.getFullYear());
console.log("mm=", ("0" + (nowDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)); // recall, month goes 0-11 in javascript
console.log("dd=", ("0" + nowDate.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

Will produce

```
yyyy= 2015
mm= 12
dd= 25
```

Then you can join the parts with "-" in the format you want. Really, there are lots of very useful examples at the MDN website. HTH.